# OpenXML - after xlsx edit Excel detects errors in file

Tags: c#, openxml, pivot-table

I have xlsx file with pivot table and some filter (pivot field), I’m trying to use OpenXML to:

- Open the file
- Modify pivot field setting
- Save the file

I’m using this simple (and ugly) code to do the job:

```
OpenSettings settings = new OpenSettings()
{
    MarkupCompatibilityProcessSettings = new MarkupCompatibilityProcessSettings(MarkupCompatibilityProcessMode.ProcessAllParts, FileFormatVersions.Office2010)
};

SpreadsheetDocument spd = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(pathToFile, true, settings);
var pivotTableCacheDefinitionParts = spd.WorkbookPart.PivotTableCacheDefinitionParts;

foreach (PivotTableCacheDefinitionPart item in pivotTableCacheDefinitionParts)
{
    var pivotCacheDefinition = item.PivotCacheDefinition;

    var d = pivotCacheDefinition.CacheFields.Where(x => (x as CacheField).Caption == "Some filter from Excel");

    foreach(var item2 in d)
    {
        if (item2.InnerXml.Contains("Some filter value"))
        {
            var a1 = item2.InnerXml.Replace("><", ">\n<").Split('\n');
            var a2 = a1.Where(x => !x.Contains("Some filter value"));
            string a3 = "";

            foreach (var item3 in a2)
            {
                a3 += item3;
            }
            a3=a3.Replace("count=\"2\"","count=\"1\"");//There are two values to choose from currently

            item2.InnerXml = a3;
        }
    }
}
```

After I save my document using:

```
spd.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
spd.Close();
```

Excel claims file is damaged and will attempt to repair it… I tried using other libraries but:

**ClosedXML** - it doesn’t see any data in pivot tables (perhaps because OLAP is used as the data source? I don’t know)

**ExcelDataReader** - doesn’t seems to support pivot tables, or support them only partially

**EPPlus** (beta version - stable didn’t work with my xlsx file) - it doesn’t seem to support edit of the pivotal fields (pivot table filters)

**MS.Office.Interop.Excel** - this works (mostly), but since we want to use this functionality on the server side, it is not recommended solution

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem (except that I don't need to modify the file for excel to claim that the file is damaged). Did you find a solution in the end ?

Comment: @NicolasR

I'm afraid not :( - we end up using MS.Office.Interop.Excel and had to install Office on the server and run our web application with "local system" privileges :/

From what I can tell You - it would seem that pivotal tables are generally not supported, or supported poorly in most free libraries (unless something changed during these 9 months...), perhaps some commercial solution support them better, but since we didn't have budget for one, we never tried.